# Create Node Error

Tags: ios, swift, neo4j

UPDATE: Make sure to set up frameworks correctly SOLVED PROBLEM

I am trying to create a node to my Neo4j database from IOS.

Here is my code after the initial connection.

```
func createNode() {
    let node = Node()
        let randomString: String = NSUUID().UUIDString

    node.setProp("name", propertyValue: "Matt Winfrey" + randomString)
    node.setProp("born", propertyValue: "1991" + randomString)
    node.addLabel("Person")

    theo.createNode(node, completionBlock: {(node, error) in
        println("new node \(node,error)")
    });
}
```

I am getting a 500 error

```
new node (nil, Optional(Error Domain=com.theo.network.error Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.theo.network.error error -1.)" UserInfo=0x7ff2b1fa9290 
{ status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
    Date = "Tue, 19 May 2015 19:44:42 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.7.6";
} }, TheoResponseCode=500, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey=There was an error processing the request}))
```

Any help would be great.